# Limit definition involving neighborhoods

Tags: calculus, limits

My calculus professor gave us the following definition:

Let $f$ be a function defined over an interval $(-\infty ,a)$. Then, $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} f(x)=L$ means that, for every $V_\epsilon (L)$ there is a neighborhood $V_N(-\infty)$ such that, if $x\in V_N(-\infty)$ then $f(x)\in V_\epsilon(L)$

I'm having trouble understanding it. What does this definition mean?

Comment: It means for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that if $x<N$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

It's definition of limit using neighborhoods:
$$V_\epsilon (L)= \{y: |y-L|<\epsilon\}$$
$$V_N(-\infty)=\{x: x < -N \}$$

More general definition limit over base you can find, for example, in Vladimir A. Zorich - Mathematical Analysis I-(2016) from page 126.